# running a method when a seekbar changes in any way

Tags: android, android-seekbar

I need to run a method every time the position of my seekbar is changed. 
It does not matter: 
how far it has moved 
the direction 
if its at the end or the start.

just that it has changed

is there a equivalent to `onclickListener()` for a seekbar.

Answer (score 0):

Use this method provided by `SeekBar` class:

```
seekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
            //progress changed
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: progress changed

Answer (score 0):

The seekbar has a  setOnSeekBarChangeListener. Check this for more details https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener.html

```
 seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(
                        new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

                @Override
              public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, 
                                                    int progresValue, boolean fromUser) {

              }

              @Override
              public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {


              }

              @Override
              public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {


              }
          });
```

Comment: after you bindById your view you can add this listener. And usually u bindById onCreate

Comment: yes sorry i get that but there are 3 sections in the code above in which do i place my method

Comment: yeah. onProgressChanged will return the new progressValue when something changes. So you can use that